# scheme, racket help. Want to return number if it fulfills the criteria

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

Here is the code:

```
(define make-simple-sv-num
  (lambda (delare)
    (let ((tal (random-from-to 100000 1000000)))
      (cond ((= (divisible? (sum-of-digits tal) delare) #t) tal)
            (else (make-simple-sv-num))))))
```

So the specification I have is to make a random 6-digit number which also is diviseable by the input-variable "delare".

My thought process with the code was to bind "tal" to the random number and then use it in the calculation and if it checks out it will return the number from "tal". If it however doesnt fill the condition it will call itself and my thought was that when it does this it would give "tal" a new random number and continue doing this until the condition is fulfilled and thus give me the wanted type of number.

Im getting this error and I don't understand how to fix it

```
=: contract violation
  expected: number?
  given: #t
  argument position: 1st
  other arguments...:
```

Comment: As the error message suggests, `=` only works on numbers. Try `equal?` instead. For booleans you could also use `eq?`, but `equal?` is usually the safer bet if you don’t understand the intricacies of how each operator works.

Comment: No need to compare a boolean to true, just use the boolean expression as a test; after all, `(P <=> true) <=> P`

Comment: Also look at the recursive call: what is wrong with it?

Comment: Thanks guys, swapping = to equal? solved it and i noticed right afterwards I had forgotten the variable input for the recursion. Seems to work as i intended it for now :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your code could be much simpler, just like:

```
(define (make-simple-sv-num declare)
    (let ([tal (random-from-to 100000 1000000)])
       (if (divisible? (sum-of-digits tal) delare)
           tal
           (make-simple-sv-num declare))))
```